# Directory.Move on remote directory causes DirectoryNotFoundException, but directory exists

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, exception, directory

We have a service that does something similar to the following:

```
var dir =        @"\\network-fileshare\logs\special\1";
var anotherDir = @"\\network-fileshare\logs\1";

if (Directory.Exists(dir))
{
    Directory.Move(dir, anotherDir);
}
```

It *sometimes* throws a `DirectoryNotFoundException` when moving the directory, saying that it "Could not find part of the path" for the directory we're trying to move (i.e. `dir`).

What baffles me is:

1. We check the directory exists, yet the exception message says it cannot be found.
2. That this error occurs intermittently. Majority of the time it works; once in a blue moon it doesn't.
3. I've verified that the directory to be moved exists in our fileshare.

Are there any other potential causes of a `DirectoryNotFoundException`?

Comment: Since it is a network share, I am guessing that transient network issues may cause the `Move` operation to fail. Is there any inner exception in the `DirectoryNotFoundException` you are receiving?

Comment: @ZoranHorvat: Unfortunately, it looks like either there is no inner exception or our logger isn't set to capture that :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network issues might cause this problem as well. You can consider using Mapped Network Drive letters but based on my experience, it's really hard to solve it unless you redesigned network structure. 
Anyway, it's just my opinion.

Comment: I'm going to assume it's due to network issues. Thanks to you and Zoran Horvat!